# Call inner function based on the argument passed to outer function

Tags: python

I have a function with one argument, and inside the function, there are inner functions with possible arguments which can be passed to the outer function.

```
def delete_alphabet(del_apha):
    def del_a():
        # code to delete a
    def del_b():
        # code to delete b
    def del_c():
        # code to delete c
    def del_d():
        # code to delete d
```

I want to call functions `del_b()`, `del_c()`, `del_d()` when I pass `a` to 
`delete_alphabet(a)`,
call functions `del_a()`, `del_c()`, `del_d()` when I pass `b` to 
`delete_alphabet(b)`,
call functions `del_a()`, `del_b()`, `del_d()` when I pass `c` to 
`delete_alphabet(c)`,
call functions `del_a()`, `del_b()`, `del_c()` when I pass `d` to 
`delete_alphabet(d)`

Can someone suggest me a way to resolve this?

Comment: What is `b`? What is `a`? What do you mean by "delete"? Hopefully not `del`... But why are these functions in a closure anyway? Could they not be defined outside? more details, please

Comment: `a` and `b` can be any string which I want to delete from some file. Not `del`.

Comment: Why not `delete_string(x)` where `x` can be `a` or `b`?

Comment: If in doubt, use a `dict`. Functions can be dict's values all right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, functions are just objects. Your approach can be as straightforward as this:

```
In [22]: def del_a(): print('deleting a')

In [23]: def del_b(): print('deleting b')

In [24]: def del_c(): print('deleting c')

In [25]: def del_d(): print('deleting d')

In [26]: funcs = {'a':(del_a, del_c, del_d), 'b': (del_a, del_b, del_d)}

In [27]: def delete_alphabet(del_alpha, funcs=funcs):
    ...:     for f in funcs[del_alpha]:
    ...:         f()
    ...:

In [28]: delete_alphabet('a')
deleting a
deleting c
deleting d

In [29]: delete_alphabet('b')
deleting a
deleting b
deleting d
```

**EDIT**
So, given the clarifications in the comments, my approach would be the following:

```
In [30]: funcs = [('a', del_a), ('b', del_b), ('c', del_c), ('d', del_d)]

In [31]: def delete_alphabet(del_alpha, funcs=funcs):
    ...:     for c, f in funcs:
    ...:         if c != del_alpha:
    ...:             f()
    ...:

In [32]: delete_alphabet('a')
deleting b
deleting c
deleting d

In [33]: delete_alphabet('b')
deleting a
deleting c
deleting d

In [34]: delete_alphabet('c')
deleting a
deleting b
deleting d

In [35]: delete_alphabet('d')
deleting a
deleting b
deleting c
```

It is much cleaner to keep some sort of mapping from string to function rather than using some `eval` hack.

Comment: If I have 20+ valid arguments to pass, it will increase number of lines in code, which won't look good, so need to take some alternative approach to avoid repetition of calling functions. `funcs = {'a':(del_a, del_c, del_d), 'b': (del_a, del_b, del_d)}` this I will have to write for all 20+ arguments.

Comment: @Sweety well, how could there be any other way other than enumerating what functions you want to call given your argument? Python cannot read your mind... Is there some way that `'a'` relates to the functions that you could get at programmatically? If so, you haven't specified that in your question.

Comment: @Sweety AH. I see what you want now. I didn't realize `del_a` wasn't being called for `'a'`. I see the pattern...

Comment: I can think of calling string as function using eval or something, but not able to figure out exact solution.

Comment: @Sweety No, it is better to use an explicit mapping.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa, your edited version of solution will do the magic!